# Why was this character banished from Tomorrowland?

Tags: plot-explanation, tomorrowland

What was the exact reason Frank was banished from Tomorrowland?

Answer (score 1):

**We are never told**:

> We’re never explicitly told, but it likely has something to do with Frank’s tachyon machine, called the Monitor. After predicting with 100% certainty that the people on Earth would destroy themselves, it seems that Governor Nix (the leader of Plus Ultra at the time) took a hardline approach to +U isolating themselves.
>
> The film only tells us that he was exiled after completing work on the Monitor. The feeling I got was that Nix’s isolationist policies caused a lot of friction in the ranks of the organization, leading to the banishment of people like Frank. [Source](http://overmental.com/content/tomorrowland-explained-exploring-the-world-of-the-future-20873)

Some details at the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrowland_(film)):

> Nix appears to greet them, and takes them to a building linked to a tachyon machine designed by Frank that can show images from the past and future, from which Casey learns that a worldwide catastrophe will happen in the near future. Because of this discovery, **Frank lost all hope and was banished from Tomorrowland.**